# Build FAILED for Notepad++ with message PostBuildEvent: The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, notepad++, post-build-event

I get a build failure due to a post build event failure when building Notepad++ in VS 2010.

Here's the message from Output window:

```
PostBuildEvent:
  The system cannot find the file specified.  
  The system cannot find the file specified.  
  The system cannot find the file specified.  
C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(113,5): error MSB3073: The command "copy ..\src\config.xml ..\bin\config.xml  
C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(113,5): error MSB3073: copy ..\src\langs.xml ..\bin\langs.xml  
C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(113,5): error MSB3073: copy ..\src\stylers.xml ..\bin\stylers.xml  
C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(113,5): error MSB3073:  
C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(113,5): error MSB3073: :VCEnd" exited with code 1.
```

Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Posting the answer for others who might run into this issue

After a little research on this subject,
I learned that the XML file names that are specified in the projects Post-Build Event have changed, so you have to update that to use the new file-names

You can fix this by modifying the project file like this:
In Visual Studio,
Select the Project (Notepad++) and choose Project > Properties from VS Menu (or hit ALT + F7)

In the Property Pages window,
expand the Configuration Properties node
then, expand the Build Events node
Select Post-Build Event to view its properties

Modify the Command Line Property to look like this:
copy ..\src\config.model.xml ..\bin\config.model.xml
copy ..\src\langs.model.xml ..\bin\langs.model.xml
copy ..\src\stylers.model.xml ..\bin\stylers.model.xml

Click OK and Build away...

Answer (score 1):

Also, be careful of spaces in the path.  I just wasted a half hour convincing myself that the paths in a Pre-Build copy step were indeed correct (they were).

Got bitten by spaces in the path.  Instead of copy d:\a path\*.dll d:\b path\ you want to quote it, like this:

```
copy "d:\a path\\*.dll" "d:\b path\"
```

Answer (score 0):

Not specific to Notepad++ but I had a similar problem with a recent post-build step. When you see...

> PostBuildEvent:    The system cannot find the file specified.

..your source path is wrong. In my case I was using the wrong relative source path. And this fixed it:

```
copy /Y $(TargetName).* $(ProjectDir)..\Latest
```